# Meteor create new: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I've just download meteor version 1.4 for windows. 
After installed, I create a project:

```
meteor create example
```

But error:

```
C:\Users\Laptop88\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.4_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:70
    hasStacks = !!e.stack;
                   ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Event I checked its version

```
meteor --version
```

It make same error.

So, I cannot create my project to learn meteor. Anyone can help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue on GitHub for that - meteor commands causes RangeError #7896:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7896

Some people there recommend:

> the only way i was able to get around this issue was by creating a new user account on windows then you login into that account then install meteor again and it would work

See: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7896#issuecomment-252478328

But read also other comments for other solutions. Some people recommend removing Node and installing a newer version.

One of the reasons that I can imagine could potentially cause that is using tail calls on a version of Node without tail call optimization which was introduced in Node 6.5.0 and is still behind the harmony flag. See:

- http://node.green/#ES2015-optimisation-proper-tail-calls--tail-call-optimisation-

Maybe the Meteor tools are using tail calls and are running Node with the harmony flag but if you have Node older than 6.5.0 then the flag doesn't turn on the tail call optimization and the call stack overflows. Just a guess.

Comment: I'm using node version 7.8.0